# A book about a magic clock that could stop time

Tags: story-identification

This book contained a grandfather who makes clocks for a living. He has a clock that when he presses it, time stops.

He has a grandson who he lives with and he is constantly being attacked by goblins, who I  think are working for someone I can't remember.

The goblins are undergoing hard labor and are trying to get the magic clock so that they can give to their master to stop time.

I read this book in 2009, so it must be at least that old.

Comment: Do you recall if the book seemed to be geared towards any audience/age group? Any recollection of the cover?

Comment: This does not seem to be Pratchett's *Thief of Time* which also features a clock that stops time, but in Pratchett's book this is decidedly a *bad* thing.

Comment: It's very different, but this very much brings to mind the book "A house with a clock in its walls"

Comment: The girl, the gold watch, and everything also leaps to mind.

Answer (score 3):

"The girl, the gold watch, and everything" (John D. MacDonald) has the grandfather (actually an uncle) who invented the watch, but not any goblins.

From the plot synopsis at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl,_the_Gold_Watch_%26_Everything):

> Kirby plays with the watch and accidentally finds out his uncle's secret: the watch can stop time for everybody but the holder, leaving him in a peculiar red-lighted world with everybody around "frozen", and effectively placing everybody else in the world at his mercy.